# Cannot run a nuxt project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, yarnpkg

I took over a project from an other company and now I am having some trouble to run their application on my PC.

When I run `yarn run dev`, I do have the following error

> nuxt-ts:2 basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")

[image: Error in PS]

What can I do, to resolve this issue?

Comment: You only need `yarn dev` unlike `npm run dev`. Also, are they using `yarn` (presence of `yarn.lock` file) or `npm` (presence of `package-lock.json`)? Then, showing us the `package.json` could be a good start. Is it supposed to work on Windows or only on an UNIX system? Where do you run the `yarn run dev`? IMO, you can unblur the screenshot, it's not really a privacy issue to know where you do work or what is your file structure. Also, did you installed some packages upfront with either `yarn` or `npm i`?